# Postfix 3.2.0 - Sending to all MX records

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp, mx-record

Firstly, apologies if I haven't included all of the relevant information in this initial post. Please let me know if I have missed anything.

I am currently running Postfix 3.2.0 and have a problem relating to MX records and defered messages. What I have identified is, if a domain our server is trying to send to has an MX record which returns no response, the message is defered. Every time postfix attempts to redeliver this message, it uses the same lowest priority MX record.

I have found examples in our mail queue which are deferred with the reason "unknown mail transport error". When I attempt to telnet to the MX records for their domain, their lowest value MX is not contactable but the others are.

We can see no traffic attempting to go from postfix to the other MX records, only the lowest value every time.

I understand that it should be standard practice for Postfix to first attempt the lowest value and then attempt to use all other MX records before deferring the message.

Can anyone advise why this isn't working for me? I'll include any postconf settings which I think are relevant below and please tell me if you need any more information;

```
ignore_mx_lookup_error = no
smtp_defer_if_no_mx_address_found = no
smtp_mx_address_limit = 20
smtp_mx_session_limit = 5
smtp_skip_5xx_greeting = yes
smtp_skip_quit_response = yes
```